# javafx - add elements to border pane at runtime

Tags: javafx

Using JavaFx (and scene builder) , I have a window (border pane) which I need to add elements at runtime.
each element has 2 labels and one table view (see [image: element example]

The final window need to be something like: [image: final]

I have search at the net, and can find any clue.

1. I'm build the element (in scene builder as separate fxml file) with Anchor pane, it is ok ?
2. How can I add X element (at run time) to the main window (as final example)

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like `BorderPane` is a bad choice for your root element here. A `TilePane` is probably a better option. Then you can just add a new element with `tilePane.getChildren().add(...);`.

Comment: Thank's but when I try to add multiple childern, I cant see nothing

    GridPane incommingMsgOverview = (GridPane)loader.load();
            GridPane incommingMsgOverview2 = (GridPane)loader.load();

            tilePaneRootLayout.getChildren().add(incommingMsgOverview);
            tilePaneRootLayout.getChildren().add(incommingMsgOverview2);

Comment: Are you setting the column and row coordinates? With a `GridPane` they will all go into the same cell by default.